# NPE when checking for object?

Tags: java

So I feel like an idiot, but I'm trying to implement collision detection, and I need to check if there is a tile next to the player. When I go to check for one, first I see if the tile I'm looking for is actually there. If it is, I proceed to select the tile and create a new object out of it. If it's not, I don't touch the tile. However, I'm getting a NPE when just trying to check for the tile! Here's the checking code (just a small section that's relevant):

```
if (world.tiles[(int) getX() / 32][(int) getY() / 32] != null) {
        Tile t = world.tiles[(int) getX() / 32][(int) getY() / 32];
```

And here's the tile array in the world class, which I pass in to the player:

```
    public Tile[][] tiles;
```

And how I create them:

```
tiles = new Tile[mx][my];
    for (int x = 0; x < mx; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < my; y++) {
            if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) {
                tiles[x][y] = new Tile(x * 32, y * 32, 32);
            }else if(y == 0){
                tiles[x][y] = new Tile(x * 32, y * 32, 32);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I get the player position and then divide by the tile size (32) to get the tile coordinates, and then check to see if the tile is null. I know I'm passing in the world to the player, so that isn't the issue. The issue is that when I look for the tile, its null! Why?

Comment: On which one of the lines in your extract do you get the NPE?

Comment: This line:if (world.tiles[(int) getX() / 32][(int) getY() / 32] != null)

Comment: That would suggest that `world` is null. Alternatively, what is the type of `getX()` and `getY()`? If this is `Integer` that too can be null.

Comment: World is not null because I checked to make sure it wasn't first.

Comment: Either `world` is `null` or `getX()` returns `null`, causing the unboxing to return an NPE.

Comment: It doesn't, I placed my player inside a tile and it works fine. It's just when I'm outside of the map that it returns null and then breaks. I'm not actually concerned that it returns null, it's just that the game closes because I'm receiving a NPE for that line, which is exactly what I was checking for.

Comment: Well, the only possible reasons for an NPE on that line is that `world`, `getX()` or `getY()` is `null`. Otherwise you are simply mistaken, either regarding the line or regarding which code is actually executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP is specific about the line causing the NPE:

```
if (world.tiles[(int) getX() / 32][(int) getY() / 32] != null) {
```

It can therefore be *nothing* to do with the fact that some of the tiles are uninitialised due to an `if` block not covering all possibilities.

Either:

1) `world` is `null`

2) `getX()` or `getY()` are `null` so the cast to `int` (a.k.a. *unboxing*) fails.

Comment: Yeah.. that would probably do it. But aren't I checking to see if it's null anyway?

Comment: @opiop65: yes you are. Problem is elsewhere: on the LHS of `!=` to be precise. I've amended my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please, on the next post, include the exact error message of where the error happens, for now I can assume two things:

- You did not initialize `world`.
- You did not initialize `rand`.

I'm urged to think that you forgot to initialize `rand`, as you seem to be used to initializing arrays correctly.

Comment: @opiop65 Good that you know it, but we didn't. It seems to have to do with that your `if`-`else` section does not cover all possibilities.

Comment: It is probably better to ask for more info in a comment, and answer later when the problem is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing all tiles as you are using two if statements:

```
 if (rand.nextInt(2) == 0) { // only executes when your random number is 0
     tiles[x][y] = new Tile(x * 32, y * 32, 32);
 }else if(y == 0){ // only executes once for each iteration of the outer for
     tiles[x][y] = new Tile(x * 32, y * 32, 32);
 }
```